# How to make expression engine not encrypt plugin output

Tags: channel-entries, plugin

I am building a plugin that takes variables from the url's query string and renders out the appropriate category ids, but when I tried testing out a category that I know exists and place the plugin tag inside the category parameters.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{exp:test_plugin}"}
   {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It outputs some hash:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product" category="M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr" dynamic="no"}
```

But when I place the plugin tag outside of the category parameter it prints out the number. Here's my plugin so far.

```
class test_plugin {
   public $return_data = "";
   public $c;
   public $s;
   public $m;
   public $t;

public function __construct($tagdata = NULL){
    $this->return_data = 28;
}



function type_name(){
    return $this->t;    
}

public function usage()
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
        :)

    <?php
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return $buffer;
}
}
```

How would I get it to print out the actual category number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just happens in really trick situations. You probably have more than one instance of the same tag on different parsing levels: one inside another tag and other one outside all of them.

The template parser replaces all the instances of the plugin with the placeholder `M00o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr`, to avoid run it over and over again, and then, because they are at different levels, it tries to parse the `exp:channel:entries` before to replace the placeholder back.

You can remove the different instance you're probably using for testing. If this isn't an option, add a false parameter to the instance inside the `exp:channel:entries` opening tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{exp:test_plugin random}" parse="inward"}
```

This will make the two instances to be different, so they will not be replaced by a placeholder and your plugin will run again.

Comment: Is there are way for me to force it not to create that placeholder?

Comment: No, but the sample code I sent should work. Is your plugin working outside other tags?

Comment: Yes the code you gave me works and the outside tag works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Scrap it. I suggest using [Low's Seg2Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat). Tried and True. Gives a ton of other variables too that you can use throughout your templates.

Comment: Was going to use that plugin but needed to format my url like www.example.com/products/filters?t=Rings&s=24_40_30&metal=33_34_45&s=34

Comment: Where is the category in that URL, `Rings`, `Metal`? If you so, you could use Mo' Variable too which could pass the correct query string to Low's plugin

Comment: Well the product type is the t variable and the other variables are sub categories that are the exact ids of each selected metal and stone types that can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it's an parse order issue.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{exp:test_plugin}" parse="inward"}`

See the docs: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order

Comment: Still rendering as that hash string